# Run function after task retry limit reached google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gae-module, maven-gae-plugin

I have the code like below:

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withRetryOptions(
                     RetryOptions.Builder
                             .withTaskRetryLimit(0)));
```

With this code the task will not retry if not an error. However, what I want to do is run another function call onRetryFailure() when 10 minutes have passed( the maximum time before retry). Any idea how i can do so?

Comment: Do you want something like error handling? A function that get executed when 10 minutes pass? I don't fully understand your question.

Comment: @J.LValtueña basically the idea is like a try catch. i want to catch when task retry limit is reached to run a function.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear under what conditions you want this `onRetryFailure()` function to run. You could:

- if you want `onRetryFailure()` to be called for any error, you could wrap up your current task code in a try-catch and launch `onRetryFailure()` as another task
- if you want `onRetryFailure()` to be called only when you hit the 10 minute time limit, at the start of your task you could add `onRetryFailure()` as another task with a 10 minute countdown and at the end of your task you could delete `onRetryFailure()` from the queue if you no longer want it to run https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/Queue.html#deleteTask-java.util.List-

Comment: For the second comment, I can't do that as only if queue passes the 10 minute mark should it run. Otherwise, it should not. Basically, if the queue is successful and does not pass 10 mins. I dont want it to run. But doing it like what you said will run after 10 mins regardless of success or failure